# How to use Cohen's Kappa as the evaluation metric in GridSearchCV in Scikit Learn?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, predictive-modeling, scikit-learn

I have class imbalance in the ratio 1:15 i.e. very low event rate. So to select tuning parameters of GBM in scikit learn I want to use Kappa instead of F1 score. My understanding is Kappa is a better metric than F1 score for class imbalance.

But I couldn't find kappa as an evaluation_metric in scikit learn here 
[sklearn.metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics).

**Questions**

1. Is there any workaround for including kappa in gridsearchcv?
2. Is there any other better metric i can use instead of kappa in scikit learn?

Comment: Fork sklearn and add support yourself; it's not that hard!

Comment: K. Are you saying modify the sklearn source file I think griddearchcv.py file? Any directions will be great.

Comment: Look at the definition of [sklearn.metrics.f1_score](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a95203b/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L479)

Answer (score 13):

[Cohen's kappa](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#cohen-s-kappa) was introduced in scikit-learn 0.17.

You can wrap it in [make_scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring) for use in GridSearchCV.

```
from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score, make_scorer
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

kappa_scorer = make_scorer(cohen_kappa_score)
grid = GridSearchCV(LinearSVC(), param_grid={'C': [1, 10]}, scoring=kappa_scorer)
```

Comment: `make_scorer()` converts metrics into callables that can be used for model evaluation. The `scoring` argument expects a function `scorer(estimator, X, y)`. So it will fail, if you try to pass `scoring=cohen_kappa_score` directly, since the signature is different, `cohen_kappa_score(y1, y2, labels=None)`. The `make_scorer` also accepts additional arguments, like `labels` from `cohen_kappa_score`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the link in the existing answer, there is also a Scikit-Learn laboratory, where methods and algorithms are being experimented.

In case you are okay with working with bleeding edge code, [this library](http://skll.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) would be a nice reference.

The Cohen's Kappa is [also one of the metrics in the library](http://skll.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/metrics.html#skll.metrics.kappa), which takes in `true labels`, `predicted labels`, `weights` and `allowing one off?` as the input parameters. Obviously, the metric would range from `[-1, 1]`.

You can also have a look at the [implementation code](http://skll.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/skll/metrics.html), just in case you would like to contribute.

Note: Cohen's Kappa is also [implemented in Scikit-Learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L260-L308).

Yes, [there](http://machinelearningmastery.com/classification-accuracy-is-not-enough-more-performance-measures-you-can-use/) [are](http://blog.dato.com/how-to-evaluate-machine-learning-models-part-2a-classification-metrics) [alternatives](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) to the Cohen Kappa metric.